# @all in JSF Ajax does not work

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

This line is inside a form tag:

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{questionBean.removeQuestion(question)}"
   value="Delete" styleClass="delete" update="@all"/>
```

However, it only works with `@form`. Nothing happens when I have `@all`. I want to be able to update not only the form but also other parts of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that  `update="@all"` not supported by primefaces

although its a bit diff question [update="@all" is not working with "ui:include ..."](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6956)

but still its being said several time that

> update="@all" does not work with PimeFaces.

another ref : [Issue 2026:  update="@all" is not working PrimeFaces ajax.](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2026)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `process="@all"` as explained [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprPartialTree.jsf).

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{questionBean.removeQuestion(question)}" 
   value="Delete" styleClass="delete" process="@all"/>
```

Comment: The `process` attribute of `<p:commandButton>` is similar to the `execute` attribute of `<f:ajax>`. It is only used to state which variables should be sumitted.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be a bug. Even if you use JSF's `<f:ajax render="@all">`, it may also does not work. To solve this, I think you can simply set the `id` attribute of the `body` tag to, for example, `mySexyBody`. Then you can do `update="mySexyBody"`.

Comment: If I do that, then I have to manually refresh the page in order to see any changes.

Comment: If you have `update="mySexyBody"`, you will get the update at the end of the Ajax call as usual.

Comment: Nope, I tried. It does not update without you refreshing the browswer manually

Comment: wow, you're rite. I have no idea why it is so. Still, you can wrap all your content with `<h:panelGroup>` and update it :P. This will surely work.