# Update input text fields with ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 5.0. I'm trying to implement set of input fields for each "user - product" where sum of values in InputText fields for each panel can only be 100%. So for example if i have 3 fields each has to be 33.333% and if I lower one value of those three fields I have to redistribute other two values i.e.(25%, 37.5%, 37.5%). Something like Humblebundle has for their charity redistribution.

When I generate dynamic fields with ui:repeat I cannot get ajax to update other fields in panel. 
XHTML file:

```
<p:tab id="tuning" title="Employee tuning">
    <p:panel header="Set employee plans">

        <p:messages />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value">
            <ui:repeat  value="#{planSetViewController.office_plan_groups}" var="office_plan_group">
                <p:panel id="#{office_plan_group.product_group.name}_group" header="#{office_plan_group.product_group.name}" style="float:left;">
                    <ui:repeat value="#{office_plan_group.product_plans}" var="product_plan" varStatus="var">
                    <p:panel header="#{product_plan.product.name}" style="float:left; width: 225px;">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="3">
                            <ui:repeat value="#{product_plan.employee_plans}" var="employee_plan">
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{employee_plan.employee.name}"/>:
                                <p:outputLabel value="#{employee_plan.plan.value}" style="margin:3px;"/>

                                <p:inputText value="#{employee_plan.percentage}"  style="width:30px;margin: 3px;">
                                    <p:ajax listener="#{product_plan.setPercentage(employee_plan)}" update="@all" />
                                </p:inputText>
                            </ui:repeat>   
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </ui:repeat>

                </p:panel>

            </ui:repeat>
        </h:panelGrid>

    </p:panel>
</p:tab>
```

And bean file:

```
public class Product_plan {

private Product product;
private List<Employee_plan> employee_plans;
private float product_plan_value;

public void setPercentage(Employee_plan employee_plan)
{
    float newPercentage;
    if(employee_plans.size() > 1)
    {
        newPercentage = (100 - employee_plan.getPercentage())/(employee_plans.size()-1);
    }
    else
        newPercentage = (100 - employee_plan.getPercentage());

    System.out.println("setPercentage: "+newPercentage);
    for(int i=0;i<employee_plans.size();i++)
    {
        if(employee_plans.get(i).getPlan().getPlan_realization_ID() != employee_plan.getPlan().getPlan_realization_ID())
        {   
            System.out.println("Setting...");

            employee_plans.get(i).setPercentage(newPercentage);
            employee_plans.get(i).getPlan().setValue((newPercentage/100)*product_plan_value);

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT:
I already tried with update="@form" and to wrap panel with static `<div id="something">` and update it, then I got this wierd error: 
   "javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression "something" referenced from ..."

Comment: possible duplicate of [@all in JSF Ajax does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744466/all-in-jsf-ajax-does-not-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give your `h:panelGrid`an id and reference it in your `update`-tag:

```
<h:panelGrid id="percentagePanel" columns="3" .... >
    <ui:repeat value="#{product_plan.employee_plans}" var="employee_plan">                   
        ...
        <p:inputText value="#{employee_plan.percentage}"  style="width:30px;margin: 3px;">
            <p:ajax update="percentagePanel" listener="#{product_plan.setPercentage(employee_plan)}" />
        </p:inputText>
    </ui:repeat>   
</h:panelGrid>
```

Compared to a normal div, `h:panelGrid` is a JSF-component and thereby found by the engine.
Apart from that, you can try `update="@parent"` to reference the next parent-component of your inputfield (in this case the panelGrid) in a relative way.

Please be sure you also have a surrounding `h:form` (there is none in your example).

Comment: update="@parent" helped. I couldn't set id to h:panelGrid because I generate grid dynamicaly.